# Difference between Atman and Jiv-Atman?

Tags: vedas

What is the difference between Atman and Jiv-Atman?

What I think is the following:

1.**Atman** is the inner-consciousness of this whole Universe.

2.**Jiv-Atman** is the inner-consciousness of a single living being like us.

Is this correct? If yes. Then how are the above two different? Are they different at all?